# Create custom field into tag of attributes in woocommerce with add_action

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook

I want to create a custom field into the terms of attributes in woocommerce, with add_action(), I have did search on the web but I can't found any hooks in this place.

Here where I want to add my custom field :

Woocommerce / Attributes / Configures Terms / Edit term

Have you an idea of which hooks I can use here for add my custom field ?
And another hooks to check the custom field after the form are post ?

Here a screenshot where I want my custom field :

[image]

Here the code that I want tu use (I just need the correct hook (hook1 & hook2) :

```
function custom_field_categorie($term)
{
    $term_id = $term->term_id;
    $args = array
    (
        'id' => 'GRE_ID',
        'label' => __('ID genre'),
        'class' => '',
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'value' => get_term_meta($term_id, 'GRE_ID', true),
        'custom_attributes' => array('readonly' => 'readonly'),
    );
    woocommerce_wp_text_input($args);
}
add_action('hook1', 'custom_field_categorie', 10, 1);

function custom_field_categorie_save($term_id)
{
    if(!empty($_POST['GRE_ID']))
    {
        update_term_meta($term_id, 'GRE_ID', sanitize_text_field($_POST['GRE_ID']));
    }
}
add_action('hook2', 'custom_field_categorie_save', 10, 1);
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, please add something where we can stick on like a picture or something the describes your problem instead of just text. Also please show us (code) what you already tried.

Comment: @Mr.Jo Thanks for your answer, I have edit my post with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go. Put this into your `function.php` file of your child theme. Tested and works:

```
add_action( 'product_tag_edit_form_fields', 'product_tag_edit_form_fields_action' );
function product_tag_edit_form_fields_action( WP_Term $term ) {
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    if ( empty( $term_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $genre_id = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'GRE_ID', true );
    ?>
    <tr class="form-field form-required term-genre-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="genre"><?= __( 'ID genre', 'your-lang-id' ) ?></label></th>
        <td><input name="genre" id="genre" type="text" value="<?= $genre_id ?>" size="40" readonly/></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

Since you originally added `readonly` to your custom args to just display the value, you don't need to save the value from this field since it can never be set empty in this form.

See the final result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have try and the custom field not appear in the edit zone, you are sure about the hook ? Thanks

Comment: We are talking about product tags - right? I've added a picture to my answer.

Comment: Could it be possible that this is a sub-category from a 3rd party plugin?

Comment: I have disabled all my plugin but nothing change, and I have also other custom field with hooks at other place and it works, but here It seem not working :/
But I see that you are at the right place with your screenshot, so I don't know why I don't see it

Comment: Sorry, I just see now that it's working in "product_tag" but I wanted the custom field in attributes "product_attributes", you know the hook for this place ?

Comment: @FlorianRichard Try replacing `product_tag` with `product_attributes` in the hook. Should work I think. Otherwise we can chat via Zoom to find a solution if you want. Something is strange with your WC structure. Normally there is no extra page for colors or something like this

Comment: I have try "product_attributes_edit_form_fields" but seems not working, the "color" attributes as create by me, and  I want to add one custom field into the terms of "color attributes". It seem at the same place than the "tag menu" but I want it for the "attribute menu", thanks for your help

Comment: So this is a custom thing from you? In this case my function can not work since I don't have your custom code for this custom attribute section.

Comment: And also I don't know a place "Edit Couleur" in WooCommerce.

Comment: The attributes was created by me (color) in attributes of woocommerce (see the first screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwNDp.jpg), and I want to create my custom field inside the terms of this attributes (screenshot 2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwNDp.jpg and 3 https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwNDp.jpg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234279/discussion-between-mr-jo-and-florian-richard).